# Access IFrame page which is on another domain

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

There is a registration form.

It works through IFrame on another domain, need to press one more button to send another value. 
Can get the script to work when I get IFrame? Or another option?

**HTML**

```
<div style="border: 0px solid rgb(201, 0, 1); overflow: hidden; margin: 0px auto; 
   width: 100%; max-width: 2000px; max-height:2500px;">
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" scrolling="no" src="https://www.angola-mmm.net/registration/" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){ $("button").click(function(){ 
       $('input[name=invite]').val("test25"); }); 
  }); 
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
<style> 
  .frame { position:absolute; } 
  iframe { margin-left: -300px; width: 1900px; height: 2000px; margin-top: -100px; } 
</style>
```

Comment: don't add everything in a comment. edit the post

Comment: Javascript can't access the contents of an iframe if it's in a different domain.

Comment: How can I do this?